# С++ работа с реестром

Tags: реестр, visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте. Я не так давно начал учить С++ (оболочка Visual Studio) и обнаружил, что работа с реестром намного сложнее (имхо) нежели на borland delphi, а потому прошу, выложите, пожалуйста, код программы (консольной win32), которая, к пример,у создаст ключ в реестре, параметр, а затем удалит. Заранее спс.

зы: кто знает, где хорошо расписано про функции работы с реестром (с примерами), киньте ссылку =)

вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib)

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    HKEY h;
    PBYTE pbBuff;
    DWORD cBuff=0;
    DWORD Type=0;
    //Откроем раздел
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,TEXT("asd"),0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE,&h)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
    //Определим объем считываемых данных
        if(RegQueryValueEx(h,TEXT("set"),NULL,NULL,NULL,&cBuff)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            if(cBuff>1)
            {
                pbBuff=new BYTE[cBuff];
                //Считываем информацию из параметра
                RegQueryValueEx(h,TEXT("set"),NULL,&Type,pbBuff,&cBuff);
                register int i;
                PBYTE tmpBuff;
                if((tmpBuff=new  BYTE[cBuff])==NULL) abort();
                switch(Type)
                {
                case(REG_SZ):
                    cout<<"Type of REG_SZ, data: ";
                    for (i=0;i<cBuff;i++)
                        cout<<pbBuff[i];//Вот тут выводится значение параметра, но после каждого символа выводится ненужный пробел(если увеличивать i на 2, то только после последнего символа он выведется) как избежать вывода пробелов?
                    break;
                case(REG_MULTI_SZ):
                    cout<<"Type of REG_MULTI_SZ, data:\n\t";
                    for(i=0;i<cBuff-1;i++)
                        pbBuff[i] ? cout<<pbBuff[i] : cout<<'\n'<<'\t';
                    break;
                case(REG_EXPAND_SZ):
                    cout<<"Type of REG_EXPAND_SZ, data: "<<pbBuff<<endl;
                    //if(ExpandEnvironmentStrings((PCHAR)pbBuff,(PCHAR)tmpBuff,cBuff)!=0) cout<<tmpBuff;
                    break;
                }

            }
            else cout<<"Value is empty"<<endl;
        }
        else cerr<<"Error in query"<<endl;
    }
    else cerr<<"Error in open"<<endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На самом деле ненамного, покажите, что сделали сами и мы поправим где не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Практическое руководство. Запись данных в реестр Windows (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bwt6b955.aspx)
- [Using the Registry in a C++ Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838625.aspx)

.

```
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, &key, &disposition) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    RegCloseKey(key);
}

RegDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сам ищу сейчас такое же для работы с реестром в win32 в современных операционках. С Win64 разобрался, код ответ для них. А Ваш код работает только под операционками до висты.

```
BOOL FileSeek::InitializeSecurityAttributes(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpAttributes)
{
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;

    // Create a well-known SID for the 'Everyone' group
    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1, SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pSID))
    //if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
    //  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pSID))
        return FALSE;

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
    ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions = EVENT_ALL_ACCESS;
    ea.grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
    ea.grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pSID;

    // Create a new ACL that contains the new ACEs.
    if (SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, NULL, &pACL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return FALSE;

    // Initialize a security descriptor
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    if (NULL == pSD)
        return FALSE;
    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
        return FALSE;

    // Add the ACL to the security descriptor
    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, TRUE, pACL, FALSE))
        return FALSE;

    // Initialize a security attributes structure
    lpAttributes->nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    lpAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
    lpAttributes->bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void FileSeek::FreeSecurityAttributes(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpAttributes)
{
    if (pSID)
    {
        FreeSid(pSID);
        pSID = NULL;
    }
    if (pACL)
    {
        LocalFree(pACL);
        pACL = NULL;
    }
    LocalFree(lpAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor);
    ZeroMemory(lpAttributes, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
}

FileSeek::FileSeek(HINSTANCE h, HWND p)
{
    _hinst = h;
    _hwnd = p;
    InitializeSecurityAttributes(&sa);
}

void FileSeek::_load()
{
if (!_theme) return;

_paths.clear();
HKEY hKey;
TCHAR s[MAX_PATH];
DWORD disposition = REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY;
wcscpy_s(s, sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s), _appVerName);
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,s,0,0,REG_OPTION_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &sa, &hKey, &disposition)!=ERROR_SUCCESS)   
    return;
wcscpy_s(s, sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s), _theme);
if (RegCreateKeyEx(hKey,s,0,0,REG_OPTION_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&sa,&hKey, &disposition) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    return;
DWORD sz=sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s),i=0;
while (RegEnumValue(hKey,i++,s,&sz,0,0,0,0)==ERROR_SUCCESS) {
  sz=sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s);
  RegQueryValueEx(hKey, std::to_wstring(i).c_str(),0,0,(LPBYTE)s,&sz);
  _paths.push_back(s);
 }
RegCloseKey(hKey);

_pathsChanged=false;
}
```